# Handling Binary Input / Output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

Which things should I consider if the input and output of my neural network are (or should be) binary values?

**Example**

I have a sequence of one-hot encoded vectors like this:

```
[0 1 0 0], [1 0 0 0], ...
```

So, regarding this there are some thoughts or questions that arise:

- Is it reasonable to use it just like it is as an input for a neural network like a `LSTM`? Or should I transform it anyhow?
- The other thing is, LSTMs return continuous values between -1 and 1 (`tanh`), should I use another activation function instead? In the end I want discrete output as well, just like my input vectors. Should I round the values?
- And what I realized and is somehow weird is that my current network tends to set all it's (inner) outputs to nearly exact -1, 0 or 1... How can I (should I?) prevent the neural network to do this?

*EDIT:* My network architecture looks somehow like this, expecting a sequence of one-hot-encoded sequences, turning it to a vector (that also tends to have only nearly zero or one values) and the decoder should return the same as the input was (autoencoder). The encoder and decoder have some stacked LSTMs.

[image]

The input looks like this (one-hot-encoded, 120 time steps with 115 vector length).

```
array([[[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ..., 
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]])
```

I have 11.000 examples.

This is my current coding:

```
 inp = Input((120,115))

 out = LSTM(units = 200, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(inp)
 out = LSTM(units = 180, return_sequences=True)(out)
 out = LSTM(units = 140, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(out)
 out = LSTM(units = 120, return_sequences=False, activation='tanh')(out)
 encoder = Model(inp,out)   

 out_dec = RepeatVector(120)(out) # I also tried to use Reshapeinstead, not really a difference

 out1 = LSTM(200,return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(out_dec)   
 out1 = LSTM(175,return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(out1)   
 out1 = LSTM(150,return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(out1)   
 out1 = LSTM(115,return_sequences=True, activation='sigmoid')(out1) # I also tried softmax instead of sigmoid, not really a difference

 decoder = Model(inp,out1)

autoencoder = Model(encoder.inputs, decoder(encoder.inputs))

autoencoder.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='RMSprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

autoencoder.fit(padded_sequences[:9000], padded_sequences[:9000],
          batch_size=150,
          epochs=5,
          validation_data=(padded_sequences[9001:], padded_sequences[9001:]))
```

But after a few epochs of training, there is no improvement anymore.

The output for the example in the beginning looks like this, not very much the same...

```
array([[[ 0.14739206,  0.49056929,  0.06915747, ...,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.03878205,  0.7227878 ,  0.03550367, ...,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.02073009,  0.74334699,  0.03663541, ...,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        ..., 
        [ 0.        ,  0.08416401,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.08630376,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.08602102,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ]]], dtype=float32)
```

The embedding vector (produced by encoder.predict) looks like this (somehow weird as all values are nearly -1, 0, or 1).

```
array([[ -1.00000000e+00,  -0.00000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   9.99999523e-01,
          1.00000000e+00,   9.99999881e-01,   1.00000000e+00,
          9.99989152e-01,   9.99999821e-01,   9.99998808e-01,
          1.00000000e+00,  -0.00000000e+00,  -4.86032724e-01,
          9.99996543e-01,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,  -0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  -0.00000000e+00,   9.99999464e-01,
         -9.99999881e-01,  -0.00000000e+00,   4.75281268e-01,
          3.01986277e-01,   6.65608108e-01,  -9.99999881e-01,
          0.00000000e+00,  -0.00000000e+00,  -0.00000000e+00,
          0.00000000e+00,  -0.00000000e+00,  -3.65448680e-15,
         -9.99888301e-01,  -0.00000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+00,
         -1.00000000e+00,  -9.90761220e-01,  -9.96851087e-01,
         -0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.47916377e-02,
         -9.99999523e-01,  -2.90349454e-01,  -9.99999702e-01,
         -7.63339102e-02,  -1.00000000e+00,  -4.16638345e-01,
         -9.99999940e-01,  -1.00000000e+00,  -9.99996841e-01,
         ..............
```

My guess is that is has something to do with my binary input / output.

Comment: How long are the vectors? Can you show us your network architecture?

Comment: In my real use-case I will end up with vectors with a length of round about 150 values. And sequences with a length of 100.

Comment: You want a generate model?

Comment: @danche: I'm interested in representing a whole sequence as a single, meaningful vector. So input and output of this model should be exactly and always the same (autoencoder). The embedding (the vector) passed from encoder to decoder is the point of my interest.

Answer (score 1):

1. Binary input is fine
2. tanh(0) = 0, but tanh(1) = 0.76. I'd suggest a RELU activation function for the first layer to get 0 or 1 activation and all hidden layers. Last layer RELU or sigmoid. Don't round the output values, use a SOFTMAX instead.
3. That's hard to tell with the limited information you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've provided additional information now. With my current architecture and coding (see my edit) using ReLu instead of tanh leads to no convergence. Softmax instead of sigmoid makes nearly no difference.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think your input is OK as it is like one-hot embedding. To my knowledge, the structure is a hybrid of seq2seq model, but you just want the final encoded embedding which you supposed to represent the whole sentence.
2. For (0,1) range, you just need to use `softmax` activation for last layer with multi-classification target. `crossentropy` or `hinge-loss` loss function is good choice.
3. Is your `W` random generated? Or you add some regulation? You can change your params distribution or some other settings to see what happened.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have tried to use ``softmax`` instead of ``sigmoid`` and there is no real difference between. I have added some more information (and the coding).